# How does the management on ccTLDs work, who gives the authority to enforce rules over the domain extensions?

Tags: domains, dns, top-level-domains, icann

I'm from Azerbaijan, and our country code top-level domain - `.az` has certain rules such as min-length of the domain name having to be at least `3` characters long. I wonder who creates such rules, as far as I know it's not ICANN's job (for ccTLDs).

There are bunch of websites that break those rules, for example: `nt.az` has two letters long domain name while it clearly breaks the *minimum length on a domain name* rule. Also, it's not only `.az`, some other ccTLDs have also rule-breaking domain names, such as `will.i.am` (`.am` - Armenian ccTLD), their rules require the domain name to be at least two letters long.

There are even more crazier domains out in the wild such as `http://ai./` - this domain does not even have a TLD!!!

**My question is, who is the responsible for those rules being obeyed and is in charge of this?**